# Unexpected end of ZLIB stream large csv file

Tags: java, csv, zlib, compression

I am trying to decompress a csv file that is in the form `name.csv.gz` and its I think its something like `600M` compressed and we'll say something in the ballpark of `7Gb` when decompressed

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
try {
        GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("/run/media/justin/DATA/2000000033673205_53848.TEST_SCHEDULE_GCO.20180706.090850.2000000033673205.x04q13.csv.gz"));

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/run/media/justin/DATA/unzipped.txt");

        int len;

        while((len = gzis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer,0,len);
        }

        gzis.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("DONE!!");
    } catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

this is the code I am using to decompress it, and at the end, I get the error `Unexpected end of ZLIB stream` and I am missing several million lines at the end of the file. I haven't found anything on google that has led me in any prosperous directions so any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I forgot a line of code at the top (*facepalm) also, I have increased the buffer size, from 2048 to 4096, and I am getting more lines after decompression, so would I be correct in assuming that I just didn't allocate a large enough buffer? (or is this a naive assumption?)

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe something wrong with .gz file? How do you create it?

Comment: The file was given to me and I have no idea how it was created....

Comment: Can anything else unzip the file, such as `unzip` or `7zip`?  If not, you have a corrupt zip file.

Comment: could you try to unpackage it with normal tools and see if any error happens? If no error happens, you can then create package file again and try it

Comment: hmmm `gunzip` yields the same error

Comment: Note that in sufficiently recent versions of Java you can just do `gzis.transferTo(out)` and avoid all the faffing around with `buffer`.

Comment: If gunzip yields the same error, then the problem is the file.

Answer (score 1):

> I have increased the buffer size, from 2048 to 4096, and I am getting more lines after decompression, so would I be correct in assuming that I just didn't allocate a large enough buffer? (or is this a naive assumption?)

This is no problem of your buffer size, it's more a problem with the GZIPInputStream.read() methode. The buffer size only declares how "often" the while-loop should read and write, cause a `bigger buffer => higher transfer rate => less loops`

Your problem is inside of the GZIPInputStream class or has something to do with the used files, maybe try a smaller file first.